# Windows 8 can't resolve internal hostnames from DNS

Tags: windows-8, dns

I have an internal DNS Server (BIND, IP: 192.168.5.5 which forwards querys for external domains to my ISPs DNS) with a local domain (example.int). I have no problems resolving hostnames from MacOS X or Linux systems, but my Windows 8 machines can't.

If I use `nslookup`, I get the following:

```
c:\>nslookup wiki.example.int
Server: UnKnown
Address: 192.168.5.5

*** UnKnown can't find wiki.example.int: Non-existent domain
```

Again, Windows can't resolve any local domain names (no problems with external domains like google.com etc.) but Linux and Mac systems can.

Answer (score 0):

does your windows system get an IP from DHCP or static?

if DHCP, have you included the forwarding DNS server in the DHCP config? doesn't seem to see the hostname of your DNS server either.

Comment: it doesn't matter if I use DHCP (192.168.5.5 is the only DNS Server I've configured) or set the values by myself, it won't work. I can resolve all external domains on my Windows machines via my internal DNS, just no *.example.int hosts :(

Comment: so, your MacOS X and Linux machines can resolve *.example.int hosts? could be a difference in the network stack. if it is internal, try making a static DNS entry in the forward lookup zone with the name wiki.example.int with the IP of the host it's on.